# The law around signing someone else’s package and withholding it without consent

Tags: australia, mail, postal-service

What does someone do if someone has signed and withheld a package without the consent of the owner who owns the package?

Answer (score 1):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states)

That is a textbook case of Obstruction of Mail under [18 usc 1702](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/1702).

> Whoever **takes any** letter, postal card, or **package** out of any post office or any authorized depository for mail matter, or from any letter or mail carrier, or which has been in any post office or authorized depository, or in the custody of any letter or mail carrier, **before it has been delivered to the person to whom it was directed, with design to obstruct the correspondence**, or to pry into the business or secrets of another, or opens, secretes, embezzles, or destroys the same, shall be fined under this title or imprisoned not more than five years, or both.

Withholding mail is obstructing the correspondence.